# Sending Simple Email in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I've read a few questions and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html on how to send emails with Rails but can't seem to get it to work within the context of my current application.

I had an existing `emailer.rb` with a couple of methods that were identical apart from the parameters they accepted were named differently so I copied their format:

```
def quotation_notification(q)
  @recipients  = q.recipient_email
  @from        = q.partner_name + "<#{q.partner_email}>"
  @subject     = "New Quotation from " + q.partner_name
  @body[:q]    = q
end
```

I then created a new view file in `emailers` named `quotation_notification.rhtml` which just contains text for the moment.

I am then calling the function from inside a different controller and sending hardcoded parameters for now:

```
q = QuotationEmail.new(:recipient_email => 'martin@domain.co.uk', :partner_name => 'Martin Carlin', :partner_email => 'martin@domain.co.uk')

# send email
Emailer.deliver_quotation_notification(q)
```

Then finally, I created a new model for `QuotationEmail`

```
class QuotationEmail

  def initialize(recipient_email, partner_name, partner_email)
    @recipient_email = recipient_email
    @partner_name = partner_name
    @partner_name = partner_email
  end

end
```

The error I get is `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 3))`

Eventually I'll be sending more parameters and hopefully attaching a pdf aswell but just trying to figure out why this isn't working first.

Comment: `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 3))`, where? you should specify the method which is giving such an error.

Comment: the log isn't very specific but it does sayy line 138 which is the line that the `QuotationEmail` object is being created.

Comment: don't know, it wasn't me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because while initialising QuotationEmail object though you think you're passing 3 params you're essentially passing only one parameter which is a hash. And initialize is expecting 3. See example below

```
class A
  def initialize(a,b=1,c=2)
    puts a
    puts b
    puts c
  end
end

a = A.new(:recipient_email => 'martin@domain.co.uk', :partner_name => 'Martin Carlin', :partner_email => 'martin@domain.co.uk')

#=> {:recipient_email=>"martin@domain.co.uk", :partner_name=>"Martin Carlin", :partner_email=>"martin@domain.co.uk"}
#=> 1
#=> 2
```

If you're trying to use named parameters instead you'd need to redefine your initialize as

```
def initialize(recipient_email:a,partner_name:b,partner_email:c)
```

and invoke it as below -

```
a = A.new(recipient_email:'martin@domain.co.uk', partner_name:'Martin Carlin', partner_email:'martin@domain.co.uk')
```

Comment: thanks, no idea why I was doing it that way, was late last night when I wrote it... changed it to `q = QuotationEmail.new('martin@domain.co.uk', 'Martin Carlin', 'martin@domain.co.uk')`